# Image Processing: API to classify text based on font-type and size

Tags: android, image-processing, fonts

I am looking for an API which can take images as input and classify/identify the text in the images based on font-type and font-size. Now, the images are screenshots of screens in a mobile app, and hence represent the perfect fonts and are not distorted like handwritten text or images of printed documents.
I went through a few of the available API's like Google Vision API but could find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Optical character recognition (OCR).
I used the IBM [Visual Recognition API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/visual-recognition/) a couple of years ago, but I've heard that the text recognition feature is not available any more.

Check out this list of OCR APIs 
https://www.programmableweb.com/category/ocr/api

I'm sure that you will find it usefull.